# Android Tablet(9.7 inch) Emulator API for Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, android-emulator, tablet

I am trying to built an application which is base on Android Tablet(9.7 inch), With Android 2.3 Gingerbread OS.
But my problem is, in my Eclipse there is no option for Tablet(9.7 inch) in 2.3 Gingerbread OS, I had tried to download from Android SDK Manager but Again there is no option for Tablet(9.7 inch) in SDK Manager.
Please Help me to solve this problem.

Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, Gingerbread is officially not a tablet OS, so no surprise here.

What you can do is enter a custom resolution that matches the one of your tablet. When creating an AVD, select "Resolution" under "Skin" and enter the resolution of your tablet. Adjust the memory and density below in the properties too.

Comment: but it is going to hide all my side buttons of emulator, like back button and all... what to do ?

Comment: @pra.... I usually just use the keyboard shortcuts instead, see the [keyboard mapping doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html#KeyMapping) for a full list of shortcuts.